# MVC5 How to Check for duplicates in Edit

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I got table with these columns :
Id , Name, Graduated

In Create Action checking for duplicate is working fine :

```
if(db.students.Any(a=>a.Name.Equals(student.Name)
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("Name","Name already exists!!")
}
```

How can I use it in **Edit Action** just only if **Name has changed** then check duplicate??
Because when I use it and just update the Graduation Date and click Save it shows duplicate error.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the entry you are editing from the `Any()` condition. It can look like this:

```
if (db.students.Any(a => a.Name.Equals(student.Name) && a.Id != student.Id)) {
    // ...
}
```

This way it will check only all the other students, not the one you are about to edit.